# remove images from NSHomeDirectory() in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi i am saving images like this:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[self findUniqueSavePath] atomically:YES];
// Show the current contents of the documents folder
CFShow([[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents"]]);

- (NSString *) findUniqueSavePath
{   
    int i = 1;
    NSString *path;
    do 
    {
        // iterate until a name does not match an existing file
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/IMAGE-%d.PNG", NSHomeDirectory(), i++];
    } while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]);

    [classObj updateimage];

    return path;
}
```

I want to remove images when the new image write in the document.

Comment: Slightly offtopic: a more correct of obtaining the path to the Documents folder is calling NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains, as Babji's answer shows. That will make your code more resilient to potential API changes in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
```